# PHP return shorthand if elseIf else not working as expected

Tags: php, return, conditional-operator

Is my return missing something?

```
return $var === 'apple' ? 'A' : $var === 'banana' ? 'B' : 'C';
```

There is only one issue is when `$var` is `='apple'` is doesn't return `A` it returns `B`

I can definitely see the $var printing `apple` So why not returning `A`

For me the statement is correct anyone have any idea?

Comment: I'd 100% avoid elseif ternary statements..

Comment: @treyBake Explain Why!

Comment: a thing called readability

Comment: @treyBake Understand But this is very short And an experience developer would not have problem with it. But the question still remains.

Comment: An experienced developer would probably not use a elseif ternary

Comment: @treyBake So you are saying the php platform such as magento, Zend etc.. Are being build but inexperience developer cause I see it use including the new Elvis operator ?:\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `()` in second condition like below:

```
return $var === 'apple' ? 'A' : ($var === 'banana' ? 'B' : 'C');
```

Output:-

https://3v4l.org/tIFGH

https://3v4l.org/rtaAE

https://3v4l.org/ZGUQW